# Powershell - add leading zeros in CSV File

Tags: powershell, csv

I built a powershell script in order to format the content of a csv file. It is working fine for the majority of columns except for one column named "Kunde_PLZ"

I want to add leading zeros to the content of that column "Kunde_PLZ" if the number inside the column is shorter than 4 digits. Trying to use padLeft(5,"0") for that.

```
Import-Csv "c:\temp1.csv" -Delimiter ";" | 
% {$_.BESTELLEINGANG = ([datetime]($_.BESTELLEINGANG)).ToString('dd.MM.yyyy');$_.LIEFERDATUM = ([datetime]($_.LIEFERDATUM)).ToString('dd.MM.yyyy');
$_.KUNDENNUMMER =($_.KUNDENNUMMER) -replace '\.', '';$_.KUNDENNUMMER =($_.KUNDENNUMMER) -replace ',.*', '';$_.KUNDE_PLZ  = $_.KUNDE_PLZ.padLeft(5,"0")   ;$_} | 
sort Kundennummer -Descending | Select * -ExcludeProperty "KUNDE_ZUSATZ" | 
Export-Csv "c:\resultfile.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -notypeinfo -Force
```

But no leading zeros are added in the resultfile for the column "KUNDE_PLZ".

I also tried using foreach , but still no leading zeros added

```
$file = Import-Csv "C:\temp1.csv" -Delimiter ";" | 
% {$_.BESTELLEINGANG = ([datetime]($_.BESTELLEINGANG)).ToString('dd.MM.yyyy');$_.LIEFERDATUM = ([datetime]($_.LIEFERDATUM)).ToString('dd.MM.yyyy');
$_.KUNDENNUMMER =($_.KUNDENNUMMER) -replace '\.', '';$_.KUNDENNUMMER =($_.KUNDENNUMMER) -replace ',.*', '';$_} | 
sort Kundennummer -Descending | Select * -ExcludeProperty "KUNDE_ZUSATZ"

$file | foreach{$_.KUNDE_PLZ  = $_.KUNDE_PLZ.padLeft(5,"0") }
$file | Export-Csv "C:\resultfile.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -notypeinfo -Force
```

Any ideas how to get the leading zeros added to the column "Kunde_PLZ" inside the csv file ?

Comment: If I open the csv with a text editor , the leading zeros are also not present. So it's not just an issue of visibility in excel.

Comment: Which other modifications  ? But I found out something else. If use padLeft(5,"A") , so prepending an A instead of a 0 it works. The 0 is somehow the problem here.

Comment: You may try `$_.KUNDE_PLZ = '{0,5:0000#}' -f [INT]$_.KUNDE_PLZ`

Comment: The zeros are added now but at the end of the number. Any chance turning those zeros into leading zeros at the beginning of the number ?

Comment: As a simple test, what output do you see if you run this: ```"aaa,bbb`nxxx,1" | convertfrom-csv | % { $_.bbb = $_.bbb.PadLeft(5, "0"); $_ } | convertto-csv```? I get ```"aaa","bbb"`n"xxx","00001"```

Comment: For me it adds leading zeros - not trailing ones.

Comment: If you want to be able to double-click this file so it opens in Excel, INCLUDING the leading zeroes, prefix the Kunde_PLZ value with a TAB character:
```$_.Kunde_PLZ = "`t{0:N5}" -f [int]$_.Kunde_PLZ``` Without that leading TAB character, Excel will treat it as a numerical value and remove the leading zeroes again..

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions . Had to check my source code again and it looks like $_.KUNDE_PLZ = '{0,5:0000#}' -f [INT]$_.KUNDE_PLZ does the trick now